# How to subtract two columns from two different tables in VB.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I've just started using VB.net and knowing that I am still a newbie, I am having a hard time subtracting columns called Quantity and Stocks from two different tables (1.Sales and 2.AddItem) I want that whenever I press a label called "Purchase" , it will subtract the number of "Quantity" in the number of "Stocks". Is it possible? Thanks.

```
    Dim connectString As String
    Dim conn As SqlConnection
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String
    connectString = "Data Source=LENOVO\MYSQL;Integrated Security=True;database = CellSalesandInventory"
    conn = New SqlConnection(connectString)
    sql = "insert into Sales (NameofUser,ProductCode,Brand,Model,NameofCustomer,Age,Sex,Address,Date,Quantity,Warranty,Price) values ('" & TextBox10.Text & "','" & TextBox1.Text & "',
   '" & TextBox6.Text & "','" & TextBox11.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & ComboBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "',
   '" & TextBox5.Text & "','" & TextBox7.Text & "','" & TextBox8.Text & "','" & TextBox9.Text & "') "
    Try
        conn.Open()
        adapter.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
        adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("You just purchased a product!Thank You!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Start by using SQL Parameters rather than gluing bits of string together for the SQL.  Then (I guess) you want toi run an update statement on the other table deducting the value of Quantity.  Also VB.NET is not vba and is not VB6

Comment: Oh okay, sorry sir, So, its like while saving  data in my table "Sales", I should update the table "AddItem"?How is it being coded when I am going to  subtract what's inside of my column "Quantity" to the other column "Stocks" from another Table?

Comment: Run one query then the other. If you want to assure that they both fail if one fails (so you dont do half the job only) use a Transaction.  You can the Quantity for this query just use it in the next.  I also suspect that query will fail due to type mismatches - everything is being passed as string even the numbers.